# wanted to make a .exe from .jar via Ekcelsior JET, but have a errors during the test running

Tags: javafx, jar, exe

I wrote a program to JavaFX and wanted to make a .exe from .jar via Ekcelsior JET, but have a errors during the test running.

The application has started with command line:

> java -cp "C:\Documents and Settings\User\Рабочий стол\qazx\dist\qazx.jar" qazx/Qazx

[image]

Comment: how I can correct this error

Comment: Exception is thrown in Main method. Debug it and find the error

Comment: This programm runs on the NetBeans